# Jquery Get Input Array Field and Display on Bootsrap Modal

Tags: jquery

I have an input of arrays.

```
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Rey">
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Jan">
```

I already pass this value to the Jquery but how can I display this array fields on my modal. The same display as I pass it

```
 $(document).on("click", ".open_modal", function () {
    $('input[name^="owner"]').each(function() {
        alert($(this).val());  already displaying the list of array in the alert text
        $(".modal-body #owner_value").val();
    });
});
```

***My Modal***

```
    <div class="modal modal-success fade" id="acceptModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-body">

            <input type="hidden" name="owner_modal" id="owner_value">
            <p id="owner_view"></p>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: `$(".modal-body #owner_view").html($(this).val());` ?

Comment: what is the expected value on `owner_value` and `owner_view`?

Comment: Try `append()` instead of `html()` as the latter will overwrite the previous values in the iteration. Better yet, use `map()` to build an array of the values and display it in one call.

Comment: it will display on the input type field but since it is 2 array the last array `Jan` will override `Rey`

Comment: Exactly my point. I added an answer to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map()` to build an array of all the values and then `join()` them together before displaying them. Try this:

```js
$(document).on("click", ".open_modal", function() {
  var values = $('input[name^="owner"]').map((i, el) => el.value).get().join(',');
  $("#owner_value").val(values);
  $("#owner_view").html(values);

  $('#acceptModal').dialog('open');
});

// jQuery UI modal setup
$('#acceptModal').dialog({
  autoOpen: false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Rey">
<input type="text" name="owner[]" value="Jan">
<button class="open_modal">Open modal</button>

<div class="modal modal-success fade" id="acceptModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="text" name="owner_modal" id="owner_value">
        <p id="owner_view"></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that the `[name^="owner"]` selector is also catching the `name="owner_modal"` input in the modal itself, hence the extra `,` in the output. I'm not sure if this is intentional so I have left it in the example. If you don't want this to happen, change the field name in the modal or improve the selector you use.

Comment: i will try to use this values on the modal to pass on an Ajax is it possible to use `owner_modal` field by just doing a serialize.

Comment: Yes, absolutely. You would do that in the same way you would any standard AJAX request. The fact it's in a modal has no bearing.

Comment: `<form id="detail_form">
         <input type="text" name="owner_modal" id="owner_value">
         <p id="owner_view"></p>
          <button type="button" id="submit"> Submit </button>
        </form>`

Comment: I am now using the  `data:$('#detail_form').serialize() ` to my Ajax but it returns an error. Is it triggered because the array has comma ,

Comment: No, that won't cause an issue. What's the eror?

Comment: `$('#submit').click(function(){            
           $.ajax({  
                url:"test-process.php",  
                method:"POST",  
                data:$('#detail_form').serialize(),  
                success:function(data) {  
                  alert(data);  
                }  
           });  
      });  `this is my ajax call

Comment: `<?php  
$number = count($_POST["owner_modal"]);  
if($number > 0) {  
  for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++) {  
        echo $_POST["owner_modal"][$i];  
    }   
 } 
 ?>  `
  
and this is my process. The error is  _Parameter must be an array or an object that implements_

Comment: I'd suggest starting a new question about this then, as we've now moved on from showing HTML in a dialog to debugging an AJAX request :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59965366/pass-and-array-to-a-ajax