# How to pass an Array to a AJAX

Tags: jquery

I have a form that has a value of array

```
    <form id="detail_form">
        <input type="text" name="owner_modal" value="Rey,Jan">
         <button type="button" id="submit"> Send </button>
    </form>
```

How can I pass this array to AJAX process

```
  $('#submit').click(function(){            
       $.ajax({  
            url:"test-process.php",  
            method:"POST",  
            data:$('#detail_form').serialize(),  
            success:function(data) {  
              alert(data);  
            }  
       });  
  });
```

test-process.php

```
<?php  
    $number = count($_POST["owner_modal"]);  
    if($number > 0) {  
      for($i=0; $i<$number; $i++) {  
            echo $_POST["owner_modal"][$i];  
        }   
     } 
?>
```

Comment: You need to [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the array on the server `$owner_modal = explode(',', $_POST["owner_modal"]);`

Comment: You also need to pass the event object to the click callback and prevent the event from refreshing the page: `$('#submit').click(function(e){ e.preventDefault; <your_code...> });`

Comment: @AlonEitan the button is `type="button"` so `preventDefault()` isn't technically needed, but it would be better to use it along with a submit button so that the form will also be sent when the return key is pressed

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for the clarification, I was sure that it would also submit the form (When there's no other `type="submit"` in the form)

Answer (score 0):

Convert string to array.

```
if (isset($_POST["owner_modal"])) {
    $owners = explode(',', $_POST["owner_modal"]);
    if(is_array($owners) && !empty($owners)) {
        foreach ($owners as $index => $owner) {
            echo $owner;
        }
    }
}
```